# If I want to use mysql database with nodejs, is waterline the middleware?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, waterline

I'm fairly new to programming and was just playing around with node js.

I was using nodejs with mongodb and mongoose to extract and save data to it.

If i wanted to use mysql, would I use something called waterline as the mongoose to the database? or am I completely off with my google searches?

Thanks in advance,

Sorry for being such a noob :(

Comment: I don't think you *need* a middleware at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a middleware to connect with MySql. But you could use ORMs like Sequelize, Bookshelf to access your database. Here are a few links to get started:

[Getting started with Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html)

[Bookshelf installation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#installation)